# valueForKey does not return the right value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

in my App there is a NSDictionary called "selectedItems" and it contains the key "Order". The value can be changed by the User.
The definition of the NSDictionary lokks like this:

```
self.selectedItems = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[self.choosedAttributes, @"Reihennfolge"] forKeys:@[@"Sorted by" ,@"Order"]];
```

I need to set a BOOL Value and I can easily set the Value like this

```
[self.selectedItems setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"Order"];
```

After this operation the value is tranfered to an other ViewController, where i want to read the value.

```
NSSortDescriptor *mySortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:(Boolean)[stvc.selectedItems valueForKey:@"Order"]];
```

This failed. The Value [stcv.selectedItems valueForKey:@"Order"] is the right one (a NSLog tells me that) But theres no effect on the GUI (ordering Persons by Name ascending or descending). But if i type a static Number or a constant like YES or NO.... it works. But the value is really the same. and this does not work. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: What does the code look like in the controller where you're attempting to use the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[stvc.selectedItems valueForKey:@"Order"]` returns a (pointer to an) `NSNumber` object.
If you just cast that to a boolean scalar, the result will always be "true", because
the pointer is not NULL.

You have to use

```
... ascending:[[stvc.selectedItems valueForKey:@"Order"] boolValue] ...
```

instead.

*Remark:* Better use `objectForKey` and `setObjectForKey` for accessing dictionary keys.
`valueForKey` is for Key-Value Coding trickery.

Even better: Use the new syntax (documented here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html)

```
stvc.selectedItems[@"Order"] = @NO;

NSSortDescriptor *mySortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"firstName"
        ascending:[stvc.selectedItems[@"Order"] boolValue]];
```

Comment: Oh, sometimes its so easy. Yes this was the right solution, thank you very much, for that and the hints for the new syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can't just cast a `NSNumber` object to `bool`,

if you try to `NSLog` like:

```
NSLog(@"%d",(Boolean)[stvc.selectedItems valueForKey:@"Order"]);
```

It'll print the value **100**. (So casting 100 boolean is equivalent to putting YES)

Instead of:

```
NSSortDescriptor *mySortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:(Boolean)[stvc.selectedItems valueForKey:@"Order"]];
```

use:

```
NSSortDescriptor *mySortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:[[selectedItems valueForKey:@"Order"] boolValue]];
```