# BOOL value changing from NO to Yes when setting up from NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have this code

```
if ([args valueForKey:@"showSetupScreen"]) {
    BOOL showSetupScreen = [args valueForKey:@"showSetupScreen"];
    NSLog(showSetupScreen ? @"YES" : @"NO");
    //  meetingConfig.showSetupScreen = showSetupScreen;
}
```

Where `args` is `NSMutableDictionary`.

`args` value in my dictionary is `NO` but when I set to `BOOL showSetupScreen = [args valueForKey:@"showSetupScreen"];` it changes into `YES`

Can someone help me in comprehending why this could be happening.

Attached Screenshot for your reference

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [valueForKey does not return the right value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19317522/valueforkey-does-not-return-the-right-value)

Comment: `[args valueForKey:@"showSetupScreen"]`return a NSNumber, so the value of showSetupScreen is the address of the NSNumber, so it mustn't be NO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `NSDictionary` (or `NSMutableDictionary`) cannot directly contain a primitive C type, such as `BOOL`. Primitive numeric types (including Boolean) in `NSDictionary` are wrapped in `NSNumber` objects. See [Numbers Are Represented by Instances of the NSNumber Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/FoundationTypesandCollections/FoundationTypesandCollections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH7-SW7) and [Most Collections Are Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/FoundationTypesandCollections/FoundationTypesandCollections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH7-SW11).

Thus, use `NSNumber` method [`boolValue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumber/1410865-boolvalue?language=objc) to extract the Boolean from the `NSNumber`, e.g.,

```objectivec
BOOL showSetupScreen = [[args valueForKey:@"showSetupScreen"] boolValue];
```

Or, more simply:

```objectivec
BOOL showSetupScreen = [args[@"showSetupScreen"] boolValue];
```

---

E.g., examples with primitive C types, including `BOOL`, `NSInteger`, and `double`:

```objectivec
NSDictionary *args = @{
    @"foo": @NO,
    @"bar": @YES,
    @"baz": @42,
    @"qux": @3.14
};

BOOL foo = [args[@"foo"] boolValue];         // NO/false
BOOL bar = [args[@"bar"] boolValue];         // YES/true
NSInteger baz = [args[@"baz"] integerValue]; // 42
double qux = [args[@"qux"] doubleValue];     // 3.14
```

For what it's worth, if you expand the values contained within `args`, that will show you the internal types for those values, and you will see that that the value associated with `showSetupScreen` (or `foo` in my example), is not a `BOOL`, but rather a pointer to a `__NSCFBoolean`/`NSNumber`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`[args valueForKey:@"showSetupScreen"]` statement returns pointer (address in memory) and it has two options: some address (non zero value) and `NULL` (zero). For C programming language `true` is any non zero value (any address in memory in our case). And for this reason you get `true` in `if` operator and in `showSetupScreen` variable. But it only tells you that there is some object in the dictionary for the specified key, but not the value of this key (the value wrapped in this object). To get this value (`BOOL` in our case), you must call the `boolValue`.